# Elementor: Flexible columns with shrinkwrapping effect

Tags: css, wordpress, elementor

is anyone here using [Elementor](https://elementor.com/)?

I'm trying to create a header with [Elementor](https://elementor.com/). 3 columns, I have a **logo** in the left, **search bar** in the middle and a **navigation menu** on the right side.

Basically, what I wanted to achieve is something like this.
[Expected Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qIlKo.png)

But what I'm currently done is [Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tSlLh.png)

Adding a border on it [Output-with-Border](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3aOv5.png)

Here is the issue when the screen/window is resized [Issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4o1aB.png)

Where it should be something like this [Expected-output-on-resize](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zvzK3.png)

To give you more details, I wanted to achieve the same functionality as the below code on Elementor.

```css
.container {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style-type: none;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.flex {
  background: #6AB6D8;
  padding: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 50px;
  border: 3px solid #2E86BB;
  color: white;
  font-size: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
}

.flex:after {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  left: 0;
  top: 100%;
  margin-top: 10px;
  width: 100%;
  color: #333;
  font-size: 18px;
}

.flex1 {
  flex-basis: auto;
}

.flex1:after {
  content: 'auto';
}

.flex2 {
  flex: 1;
  flex-basis: fill;
}

.flex2:after {
  content: 'fill-remaining-space';
}

.flex3 {
  flex-basis: min-content;
}

.flex3:after {
  content: 'min-content';
}
```

```html
<ul class="container">
  <li class="flex flex1"><div style="background: #000; width: 200px;">Logo</div></li>
  <li class="flex flex2"><div style="background: #000; width: 100%; margin-right: 10px; margin-left-10px;">Search-Bar</div></li>
  <li class="flex flex3"><div style="background: #000; width: 350px;">Navigation Menu</div></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Are you using Elementor Pro and it's default widgets for `Search-Bar`, `Navigation Menu` and `Logo`?

Comment: No, I'm just using the Free Version of Elementor. For the `SearchBar`, I'm using the [Advanced Woo Search](https://wordpress.org/plugins/advanced-woo-search/) while the `Logo` is `Custom Header Logo`, I'm not sure if it is included in the Elementor Free Version but it is in the widget list and its functionality is the same as the default logo so I use it and the `Navigation Menu` is from the [OceanWP](https://oceanwp.org/) Plugin and it is also free version.

Comment: Great, check my posted answer.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's possible by using the free version of Elementor. However you can still achieve what you want.

The idea is by using the `ShortCode`.

Since you are using [OceanWP](https://oceanwp.org/) theme plugin then you will need to install the [Ocean Extra](https://wordpress.org/plugins/ocean-extra/) plugin first.

**STEP 1: Create templates**
You will need to create a template for those four elements by navigating into your WordPress `Dashboard` > `My Library` then create the templates by clicking the `Add New` button and name them with the following:

- **search-bar**
- **logo**
- **navigation-menu**
- **header**

Each of the templates you created will generate a `shortcode` so take note of them.

**STEP 2: Edit the templates you created using Elementor**
Edit the template you created using Elementor, on the `search-bar` use the widget of [Advanced Woo Search](https://wordpress.org/plugins/advanced-woo-search/#installation) since you said you are using its plugin, you may also use its shortcode if it has a shortcode,just search for the widget `ShortCode` in Elementor then drag and drop it into the section, input the shortcode of the Advanced woo search then make the `width full` and `100%`, save and publish it.

In the template `Logo`, edit it again using Elementor then use the widget `Custom Header Logo` as you said you are using it, then go to `Advanced` > `Positioning` then set the `Width` to `Inline(Auto)` and `Vertical Align` to `Start`. This will position the logo in the Left side of the section otherwise, position it into the left side, save and publish it.

Edit the template `navigation-menu` using Elementor, from the widgets search for `Custom Header Nav` and use it then position it into the right side of the section.

***NOTE: You don't have to change anything in the section of Elementor.***

The last thing is the `header` template, before editing the `header` template, you must `create a shortcode` with the tag you created, so don't edit it yet, proceed to next step.

**STEP 3: Create a shortcode under your function.php**

```
function cs_custom_header_shortcode( $atts ) {  
    $logo = do_shortcode('[shortcode of logo template]');
    $search = do_shortcode('[shortcode of search-bar template]');
    $nav = do_shortcode('[shortcode of navigation-menu template]');
    echo '
    <div class="cs-flex-container">
        <div class="cs-flex-item cs-flex1"><div>'.$logo.'</div></div>
        <div class="cs-flex-item cs-flex2"><div>'.$search.'</div></div>
        <div class="cs-flex-item cs-flex3"><div>'.$nav.'</div></div>
    </div>
    ';
}
add_shortcode( 'cs_custom_header', 'cs_custom_header_shortcode');
```

copy and paste the above code into your `function.php`, I've use your idea, I just replace the tag into `div`.

Notice the `do_shortcode('[shortcode of logo template]');`, replace the `[shortcode of logo template]` with the shortcode of those templates you created.

Your shortcode now for this is `[cs_custom_header]`.

**STEP 4: Edit the `header` template using elementor and use the shortcode `[cs_custom_header]`.**

Edit the `header` template using Elementor, then from the list of widget search for `ShortCode` then drag and drop it into the section and input the following shortcode `[cs_custom_header]`.

**STEP 5: Edit the `CSS` style**.
Go to your Wordpress `Dashboard` > `Appearance` > `Customize` > `CSS/JS` and input the following CSS style.

```
.cs-flex-container {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style-type: none;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.cs-flex-item {
  background: #6AB6D8;
  padding: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 50px;
  border: 3px solid #2E86BB;
  color: white;
  font-size: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
}

.cs-flex-item:after {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  left: 0;
  top: 100%;
  margin-top: 10px;
  width: 100%;
  color: #333;
  font-size: 18px;
}

.cs-flex1 {
  flex-basis: auto;
}

.cs-flex1:after {
  content: 'auto';
}

.cs-flex2 {
  flex: 1;
  flex-basis: fill;
}

.cs-flex2:after {
  content: 'fill-remaining-space';
}

.cs-flex3 {
  flex-basis: min-content;
}

.cs-flex3:after {
  content: 'min-content';
}
```

You may also use it into your css child theme and again I just use your css code.

With the code you provided, I assume you know how to work on most of the thing but just lack on idea of how to do it using Elementor so I won't be very specific in everything, just a guide.

The steps maybe long, but you will achieve what you want with it.

Have a nice day.

Comment: I actually give up on it 3 days after not getting any suggestions. I already change the structure of my header to something else which is I don't like. I tried your steps and yep, it works as expected. However, I still have some padding issues and will fix them by myself. I'm using the `header` template now and I like it. Thank you so much for your effort! It should be added to the Elementor Free Version.